# Ubuntu: error while loading shared libraries: libqjsonrpc.so.1

Tags: json, ubuntu, rpc, json-rpc, qjson

I have downloaded the QJsonRpc (https://bitbucket.org/devonit/qjsonrpc/overview) and placed in the project directory in Ubuntu 14.04. While running the exe.file, it shows the following error: error while loading shared libraries: libqjsonrpc.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.

My project is placed in Home directory

Comment: what is `exe.file`? what is the output of `ldd your_executable`?. Have you run `sudo make install` after compiling QJsonRpc?

Comment: I don't know how to compile QJsonRpc after downloading it? Can you guide me about this

Comment: You must open a console in the downloaded folder and execute the commands shown in the **BUILDING** section of https://bitbucket.org/devonit/qjsonrpc/src/master/

Comment: Hi dear, I have successfully created the build directory with their subdirectories and files with commands mentioned in the BUILDING section. Still, it shows the same error, Do I need to follow the more steps? Thanks

Comment: what is the output of `ldd your_executable`?.

Comment: Error while loading shared libraries libqjsonrpc.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory:

Comment: That is not the result format of ldd

Comment: Can i share with you the link of project code available on the internet that i was trying to run?

Comment: Have you run `make install` or `sudo make install` ?, execute the second command since when installing the libraries you need permissions.

Comment: Wao Nice. Now, it is working. Thanks a Lot Dear